# How to add Spring WebMvcConfigurerAdapter jar to classpath?

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, dispatcher

I want to use Spring **WebMvcConfigurerAdapter** in my project. It's in the **org.springframework.web.servlet** jar itself. but when I'm trying to import this class it's can't be imported. Same problem is happening with **ComponentScan**.It's in the **org.springframework.context** jar.But when I'm importing the class,same problem is happening in the eclipse.
Please share some solution for this problem

Comment: What problem?  Whats the error message?  Red X's?  Red !'s?  Portal to another dimension?  None of us, as far as I know, are clairvoyant and we can't guess what your are seeing, so please show what's happening.

Comment: I said that the classes couldn't be imported. So obviously there should be some rted mark whenevr the class is used in my project.

Comment: Ok, and is there an error message that goes along with the red X?  Maybe something to do with "XXX cannot be resolved"?  Is there any Project-level error messages, maybe something along the lines of "Could not resolve Project XXX".  Are all your JARs in a separate project, or all one project?  How are you importing/creating the project files?  Manually?  Maven?  Gradle?  Your question in the equivalent of bringing your car to the mechanic and just saying "It's broken" but not giving any clue as to what symptoms make you think it's broken.

Comment: All my jars are in the same project.Jars are in the lib folder of WEB-INF. Yet eclipse can't find the class.

Comment: I think we are still missing a ton of details.  However, I will try to give you at least some guidance.  Eclipse will resolve dependencies one of several ways.  First, directly via the project's Java Build Path by adding the JARs to the Library tab.  Second, indirectly by importing a JAR library that has the required JARs listed in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.  Third, as exported libraries from another Project you reference in the projects Java Build Path.  I would start with the first: check that the JARs are all listed in the Java Build Path's Library tab. <cont.>

Comment: <cont.> So, to the issue of details.  If I knew you were using Maven, which can generate the Eclipse project files, I could recommend doing a `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` to re-generate the .project and .classpath files Eclipse uses for a project, which might resolve your issue.  Or, if I knew you were using Gradle you could do a `gradle eclipseClasspath` to do the same.  These details give us clues as to how we can possibly help you, since we are not standing directly behind you.  It's very frustrating to have to fish all the details out over several comments.